# Get width/height of image outside scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a mouseover effect that enhances an image, and scales the image back to its original size on mouseout.

```
$("div.elby_product_thumb img").mouseover(function() {
    var originalHeight = $(this).width();
    var originalWidth = $(this).height();

    $(this).css('border','2px solid #f2f2f2');
    $(this).css('z-index','500');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "top": "-50px",
        "left": "-50px",
        "width": "200px",
        "height": "200px"
    }, 200);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('border','none');
    $(this).css('z-index','1');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "top": "0px",
        "left": "0px",
        "width": originalWidth + "px",
        "height": originalHeight + "px"
    }, 200);
});
```

Although this results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: originalWidth is not defined` because `originalWidth/Height` is not in the scope of the mouseout handler function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare variables out side of `mouseover` and `mouseout` to make it global and assign values within `mouseover`

```
var originalHeight;
var originalWidth;   

$("div.elby_product_thumb img").mouseover(function(){
      originalHeight = $(this).width();
      originalWidth = $(this).height();
     $(this).css('border','2px solid #f2f2f2');
        $(this).css('z-index','500');
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "top": "-50px",
            "left": "-50px",
            "width": "200px",
            "height": "200px"
            }, 200);
}).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('border','none');
        $(this).css('z-index','1');
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "top": "0px",
            "left": "0px",
            "width": originalWidth + "px",
            "height": originalHeight + "px"
        }, 200);
});
```

**Edit:** If you do not need to declare the variables in window scope to make them full global you can make enclosure for both events as @roasted suggested.

```
(function(){
   var originalHeight;
   var originalWidth;   

   $("div.elby_product_thumb img").mouseover(function(){
    //your code
   }).mouseout(function(){
    //your code
   });
})();
```

Comment: You could put it inside anonymous function, thats way no need to make it 'full' global: (function(){...})()

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can use a `data` parameter to store the original size. Secondly, you can cache the selector and reduce the number of calls you make to it, like this:

```
$("div.elby_product_thumb img").mouseover(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el
        .data('originalHeight', $el.height())
        .data('originalWidth', $el.width())
        .css({
            'border': '2px solid #f2f2f2',
            'z-index': '500'
        })
        .stop().animate({
            "top": "-50px",
            "left": "-50px",
            "width": "200px",
            "height": "200px"
        }, 200);
}).mouseout(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el
        .css({
            'border': 'none',
            'z-index': '1'
        })
        .stop().animate({
            "top": "0px",
            "left": "0px",
            "width": $(el).data('originalWidth') + "px",
            "height": $(el).data('originalHeight') + "px"
        }, 200);
});
```

Comment: This is a better way than using global

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply define this two variables "originalHeight", "originalWidth"
outside the mouseover function. Then you can simply use it in "mouseover" and "mouseout", as global for this two events.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan has a better answer.